# Downloading on Android - FileNotFoundException but file exists

Tags: java, android, download, filenotfoundexception

I tried to download a file from a server in Android but all I get is a FileNotFoundException.

My download method works fine for all files I give it, but not on this one specific url.
The url it is not working on looks like this: http://server.com/download.aspx?action=geta&sid=12345&file=somedata.xml&client=android

I see no errors in the url, if I enter it into a webbrowser, i imediately get the file. The permissions are also allright, I can use the method to download every other file from the server, for example with "getfile" instead of "get", but the file i want to download is only accessible through "get", so i can't just replace it.

Anyway, here is my download method:

```
public String downloadURL (URL url, String fileName) throws IOException {
    String destination = null;

    try {           
        destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" 
                + "myapp/" + fileName;

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destination);

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int bytes = 0;

        while ((bytes = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer,0, bytes);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DOWNLOAD URL", "downloading file failed due to " + e.toString());
    }

    return destination; 
}
```

I'm kind of in despair here, I searched StackOverflow for a while but got no solution, and would be very grateful for help.

EDIT: The error stack, if that is, what I think it is:

> 08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myfirm.com/download.aspx?action=get&sid=6d62429x-4e1c&file=data.xml&client=android
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:532)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at myapp.cont.fetch.Downloader.downloadURL(Downloader.java:412)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at myapp.cont.fetch.Downloader.getData(Downloader.java:465)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at myapp.cont.fetch.Downloader$GetFilesTask.doInBackground(Downloader.java:245)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at myapp.cont.fetch.Downloader$GetFilesTask.doInBackground(Downloader.java:1)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
>   08-16 17:32:58.530: WARN/System.err(24754):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)

Comment: Could you edit your post, and provide error stack? Preferably using pastebin link or similar.

Comment: remember, if you are using the emulator, you need to amount SD card, in the avd manager.

Comment: did you find the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your destination file. Either the directory **myapp** does not exist on the SDCard or you didn't include in your `manifest` the permission to write on the SD Card:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: The permissions are all set and the directory does exist, it even works for every other file, but not with "get" and "data.xml".

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without more precise info, but my hunch is that you need to create your local file before you try to write to it:

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" 
            + "myapp/" + fileName);
 if(!f.exists()){
   f.createNewFile();
 }
 OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Comment: The thing is, that this method works for every other file. I'm sorry if there is no more info, but this is why I am myself quite desperate.

Comment: It seems like this only happens on one of our servers but not on the others, so it seems like this is no problem with my code, but I am still wondering, because the url which causes FileNotFound works in the browser...

Answer (score 0):

create a connection for the URL object.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

and then read inputstream as `conn.getInputStream();`

I had a similar issue. Fixed this way.